# WPF Save WebBrowser HTML

Tags: c#, html, wpf, browser

Does anyone (please) know how to do this? I thought that there would be an easy way to achieve this but can't find anything about saving the contents of WebBrowser HTML.

Answer (score 24):

You might try something like this:

(Assuming C# 4 and WPF 4)

```
dynamic doc = webBrowser.Document;
var htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;
```

Works for me...

Comment: I searched everywhere for a simple solution and this is it! Brilliant! No need to use COM or reference any other libraries.

Comment: will that save any related images as well or not ?

Comment: This code throws this exception for me: 'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'documentElement' Any thoughts ?

Answer (score -3):

Yous should use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse objects. Simple sample (found in web, tested, working):

```
HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(@"http://www.[pagename].com");
myWebRequest.Method = "GET";

HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();

StreamReader myWebSource = new StreamReader(myWebResponse.GetResponseStream());

string myPageSource = string.Empty;
myPageSource = myWebSource.ReadToEnd();
myWebResponse.Close();
```

Comment: I don't think that's what I need as I am altering the HTML in the WebBrowser control (adding new divs, form controls). I need to save the HTML directly from the control, not from a URL.