# Reading json data from a WPF WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, ajax, webbrowser-control

How would I go about reading the json data returned by a web server in response to the ajax calls/polls from the html document inside my wpf web browser control? The connection between the client and server is secured.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Either you're asking how to display json in a web browser control or you're asking how to deserialize the json into e.g. a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to call C# code from Javascript and vice versa i.e. call Javascript in the page from C#. Depending on your scenario you could use either of these to return the JSON string.

See this article for more [information](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article840-working-with-webbrowser-in-wpf.aspx)

If you don't have control over the html page i.e. you cannot change it you might have to parse the whole page, you can get the page like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762063/1045728)